Help for a probability test comparing presence/absence of expected number between two entities
I have a probability problem I don't know how to solve.
In that problem I have a genome of a VirusA with 100 genes for which I know 20/100 are unique to this virus.
In the other end, I have another incomplete VirusB (I did not sequence all the virus) where 40/100 of the VirusA genes are present in VirusB. While 0 of the unique VirusA genes are present in VirusB.
My question is then the following :
What is the probability of seeing that by chance ? I mean what is the probability that none of the unique genes of VirusA have not been sampled in VirusB by chance ?
I need this probability to show that since I don't get any of VirusA genes in VirusB, evene if VirusB is incomplete, the probability of it to be the same as VirusA is very low.
Would this approach be correct ?
# Total genes in VirusA
total_genes <- 100

# Unique genes in VirusA
unique_genes <- 20

# Genes present in VirusB
genes_in_virusB <- 40

# Non-unique genes in VirusA
non_unique_genes <- total_genes - unique_genes

# Calculate the binomial coefficients
total_ways <- choose(total_genes, genes_in_virusB)
non_unique_ways <- choose(non_unique_genes, genes_in_virusB)

# Calculate the probability
probability <- non_unique_ways / total_ways
print(probability)


Can you clarify a point? Did you sequence the whole A virus, but not B, or did you sequence both viruses incompletely? Is your data the "population" for A and a "sample" for B, or are they both "samples"? In the first case, your data says that 60% of the B sample is not found in the A population; that should be enough to declare them differemt? IN the 2nd casse, we need to know how  much (proportion) of each virus was sequenced.

Hello, the Virus A is complete, so we know all its gene content. While for the virus B only a portion of its genome was recovered, that's why I need to have statistics to say that even if a tiny portion of B was sequenced, it is unlikely that it is the same as A. In the first case A would be representative of the population, and B a sample.

OK, then you can already say that you found 60 genes which are in B and not in A. There is no way they can be "the same" (or else, where would these 60 genes be in A? So B may -or not - have all the same genes as A (because you did not sequence the full B virus), but B definitively has -at least- 60 genes which are not in A). QFD? So there is no statistics required, since A is the population. Am I missing something?

No, 40 is the number of genes of A present in virusB as well. The all problem is to figure out wether B is the same virus as A given that what makes virus A being Virus A and therefore unique is to have one of the 20 unique genes of A. The thing is that we do not get any of the 20 genes unique to A in virus B. BUT we did not sequence virus B completely, so we might have missed these genes by random chance, and I want to calculate this chance.
